# $window in angular.js throws exception when using $window.open

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get this error thrown:

```
Error: Error: [$parse:isecwindow] Referencing the Window in Angular expressions is disallowed!
```

When I try using $window.open/window.open in angularjs.

Generate.html

```
<div class="print-report-footer" ng-show="vm.clicked">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.downloadFile('pdf')">PDF</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.downloadFile('xls')">XLS</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.downloadFile('csv')">CSV</button>
</div>
```

Generate.ctrl.js

```
    function downloadFile ( fileType ) {
        var path = '/images/reports/DistrictSchoolReport.' + fileType;
        return $window.open( path );
    }

    self.downloadFile   = downloadFile;
```

This is the code that I have used. What do I need to do to avoid this error thrown everytime I use $window.open?

Comment: can you try $window.open(path); return;
Looks like you are calling that function from the view, which is causing the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the error is being throwing at $window not elsewhere? You could have scoping issue where `this` is being initialized as `window`.

Comment: BTW, you also can use `window.open` and not `$window.open`. also be sure that this code runs under angular project

Comment: I first tried window.open @MaximShoustin and also throws the error, went to other stackoverflow questions and found $window hoping that it would have solved the problem. I updated the question with the html file calling the downloadFile method maybe it would help.

Comment: @MaximShoustin `window` isn't testable, `$window` is

Comment: Can you split the code in your question into separate parts identifying which file they're in. At the moment, it doesn't look like your `downloadFile` function is part of a controller. Seeing as you're using the *controller as* syntax, it should at least be `this.downloadFile = function...`

Comment: Plunker demo here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/cQdQiPJg0P0Z2wChSNKk?p=preview. It's the `return` statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running $window.open() from the view. Do this instead: (don't use return)

```
function downloadFile ( fileType ) {
    var path = '/images/reports/DistrictSchoolReport.' + fileType;
    $window.open( path );
}
```

Comment: It's definitely the `return` that's causing the error

Comment: @Phil i know this problem is solved, but can you guys explain to me why the return statement causes this error?

Comment: you were returning the $window.open() function, which was being run from the html template view. Although window is accessible from the document, it's not accessible from the view in this case.